# What does $dummy and non-parameter split mean in Perl?

Tags: perl, split, classification, dummy-data

I need some help decoding this perl script. $dummy is not initialized with anything throughout anywhere else in the script. What does the following line mean in the script? and why does it mean when the split function doesn't have any parameter?

```
($dummy, $class) = split;
```

The program is trying to check whether a statement is truth or lie using some statistical classification method. So lets say it calculates and give the following number to "truth-sity" and "falsity" then it checks whether the lie detector is correct or not.

```
# some code, some code...
$_ = "truth"
# more some code, some code ...

$Truthsity = 9999
$Falsity = 2134123

if ($Truthsity > $Falsity) {   
    $newClass = "truth";      
} else {
    $newClass = "lie";     
}

($dummy, $class) = split;

if ($class eq $newClass) {
    print "correct";
} elsif ($class eq "true") {
    print "false neg";
} else {
    print "false pos"
}
```

Comment: `(undef, $class) = split " ", $_` and `$class = (split " ", $_)[1]` are equivalent lines to `($dummy, $class) = split` (well, as long as no one goes and starts using `$dummy`)

Comment: ah yes, i've found there is a $_ in the code

Comment: Ok, but `$_` doesn't have to appear in the code explicitly.  It's implicitly set by a lot of operations.  `perldoc perlvar` and search for "ARG".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
($dummy, $class) = split;
```

Split returns an array of values.  The first is put into `$dummy`, the second into `$class`, and any further values are ignored.  The first arg is likely named dummy because the author plans to ignore that value.  A better option is to use undef to 
ignore a returned entry: `( undef, $class ) = split;`

Perldoc can show you how split functions. When called without arguments, split will operate against `$_` and split on whitespace.  `$_` is the default variable in perl, think of it as an implied "it," as defined by context.

Using an implied $_ can make short code more concise, but it's poor form to use it inside larger blocks.  You don't want the reader to get confused about which 'it' you want to work with.

```
split ;                      # split it
for (@list) { foo($_) }      # look at each element of list, foo it.
@new = map { $_ + 2 } @list ;# look at each element of list, 
                             # add 2 to it, put it in new list
while(<>){ foo($_)}          # grab each line of input, foo it.
```

`perldoc -f split`

> If EXPR is omitted, splits the $_ string.  If PATTERN is also omitted, splits on
>   whitespace (after skipping any leading whitespace).  Anything matching PATTERN 
>   is taken to be a delimiter separating the fields.  (Note that the delimiter may 
>   be longer than one character.)

I'm a big fan of the ternary operator `? :` for setting string values and of pushing logic into blocks and subroutines.

```
my $Truthsity = 9999
my $Falsity   = 2134123

print test_truthsity( $Truthsity, $Falsity, $_ );

sub test_truthsity {
  my ($truthsity, $falsity, $line ) = @_;
  my $newClass = $truthsity > $falsity ? 'truth' : 'lie';
  my (undef, $class) = split /\s+/, $line ;

  my $output = $class eq $newClass ? 'correct' 
             : $class eq 'true'    ? 'false neg'
             :                       'false pos';
  return $output;
}
```

There may be a subtle bug in this version.  `split` with no args is not the exactly the same as `split(/\s+/, $_)`, they behave differently if the line starts with spaces.  In fully qualified split, blank leading fields are returned.  `split` with no args drops the leading spaces.

```
$_ = "  ab cd";
my @a = split             # @a contains ( 'ab', 'cd' );
my @b = split /\s+/, $_;  # @b contains ( '', 'ab', 'cd')
```

Answer (score 3):

From the documentation for [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html):

> split /PATTERN/,EXPR
>
> If EXPR is omitted, splits the $_ string. If PATTERN is also omitted,
>   splits on whitespace (after skipping any leading whitespace). Anything
>   matching PATTERN is taken to be a delimiter separating the fields.
>   (Note that the delimiter may be longer than one character.)

So since both the pattern and the expression are omitted, we are splitting the default variable `$_` on whitespace.

The purpose of the `$dummy` variable is to capture the first element of the list returned from split and ignore it, because the code is only interested in the second element, which gets put into `$class`.

You'll have to look at the surrounding code to find out what `$_` is in this context; it may be a loop variable or a list item in a `map` block, or something else.

Comment: It might also be worth pointing out that convention would be to use `(undef, $class) = split` to avoid introducing unused variables that only cause confusion.

Answer (score 2):

If you read the [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html), you'll find that:

- The default for the first operand is `" "`.
- The default for the second operand is `$_`.
- The default for the third operand is `0`.

so

```
split
```

is short for

```
split " ", $_, 0
```

and it means:

> Take $_, split its value on whitespace, ignoring leading and trailing whitespace.

The first resulting field is placed in `$dummy`, and the second in `$class`.

Based on its name, I presume you proceed to never use `$dummy` again, so it's simply acting as a placeholder. You can get rid of it, though.

```
my ($dummy, $class) = split;
```

can be written as

```
my (undef, $class) = split;   # Use undef as a placeholder
```

or

```
my $class = ( split )[1];     # Use a list slice to get second item
```

Comment: That `0` is a bit of an oddball, given that `3` would split the string into 3 at most, `2` into 2, and `1` into a single string.

Comment: @Zaid, `-1` and `0` don't impose a limit. `0` also trims empty trialing fields.